# LED - Downlights/Recessed Lights - Quality, Safety

Tags: power-supply, power, led, safety, led-driver

I been looking to upgrade old recessed can lights with "modern" LED slim potlights, Market is flooded with different brands.

I went out and purchased a bunch of LED lights, removed the drivers, and snapped some pictures.

And I'm blown away by how much the design varies between the cheapest and most expensive brands.
While I don't understand any of the circuits, the amount of elements between brands is significant.

I take SAFETY over longevity, as I have seen some pictures on Amazon of LED drivers catching on fire.

I'm leaning toward the **PS-B** ( Second picture ) as they are not the cheapest and not most expensive. The only concern is that the Driver enclosure is plastic (PBT) which is placed in metallic box where power terminates, other units have metal separation between wiring and driver.

To get to the topic, my question:
Could someone please explain to me why some of the boards have so few components? Is this a more modern design of the led driver, safety cost cutting?

What safety elements should an exemplary LED driver have?

Update / components PS-B unit

1692L-308 / Led Driver Chip with built protection / https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AL1692-30B.pdf

cs98p171co / 8-bit general purpose MCU

I'm guessing its nice that device is using dedicated driver chip ?
But I don't understand what is the purpose of the MCU!?

[image: Led Drivers]

Comment: Some have isolation, some don't. You can't see isolation quality without dismantling the transformers. Some have more filter componets, some less. Some may not need much filtering if the switching is handled better. Modern design might be more integrated than older design with more componets. And some of those may not be even intended for exporting to your market area so they might not adhere to standards required.

Comment: Without extensive reverse engineering and/or destructive testing it's hard to say which are better for safety. More important would be to buy something from a local distributor made by a reputable vendor in your country. This means you have someone to take to court if the item injuries someone and also means that the product will probably be up to code. Avoid generic items from Amazon/ebay/AliExpress at all costs.

Comment: Understood, thank you, I expected response like this that you can't judge book by its cover.

That's my plan I'm thinking to stick with "Commercial Electric" brand which is owned by Home Depot I believe - this is the PS-B unit.

Comment: "What safety elements should an exemplary LED driver have?" <- it should have a UL listing (or any equivalent listing agency - CSA, TUV, ETL, etc). Installing unlisted electrical devices in your house is likely against whatever local "code" applies wherever you live, and will almost certainly void your home's insurance policy if one of these unlisted devices catches fire and causes damage.

Comment: @brhans
Sure, all those devices ETL listed on "Paper" - but reality is always different of what you get... examples in the comment below to Amazon, the particular devices was ETL listed.

Answer (score 1):

The most magnetic parts (5) are in PS-B might also benefit in features (dimmable range) maybe better efficiency maybe lower temp rise then plastic maybe is OK.  More LC filters can also make for lower noise emission and better noise immunity to switched-off fan motor voltage spikes or coffee heaters to flick off LEDs for a fraction of a cycle, which even Philips PAR Lamps are susceptible to this trivial nuisance.

Safety is hard to see without design details, statistics, customer feedback and testing but you should expect good safety from major brands. Higher temperature, more noise, no dimmer contrability might occur in simpler designs or immunity from tolerance to line voltage.

The colour temperature and rendering indiex are also important, as I expect you want to improve lighting quality, efficiency and maintenance costs.

PAR Lamps might be the best replacement from good brand-names using your existing recessed receptacles will usually fail in the OFF state and not overheat.Colour temps such as  Warm or Neutral are better for the eyes or perhaps cool for reading a book perhaps are personal choices. Tri-phospor are better for reading but hard to find with variable tint.

I have never seen ceiling pot LED lamp fires from Amazon, so perhaps you can share some links.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to respond.
Could you please tell me what magnetic parts are (Google) not helpful, and I assume its good to have them.

And yes thank you all claim to have CRI90 and the PS-B unit actually is switchable from 2500K-6000K for light color range.

I did consider PAR but wife wants something more modern.

As far as the "fires" unfortunately I didn't save any links but just found one of them, Please see picture below, LED driver melted ?

https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61gG3Xsfd+L.jpg

Comment: magnetics include chokes, switching inductors that transform voltage or current and/or filters. basically L= inductor varies widely in construction for different frequency range, current, voltage , DCR losses and number of windings. https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hP1Z.jpg

Comment: Thank you so much Tony, I assume its good thing to have them vs not having them.
This is clearly above my head haha.
I figured more components = higher quality/safety since less cost cutting lol

Comment: Normally they're used to gain efficiency or more features while adapting to the input and load changes.

Comment: I'm leaning towards the PS-B ( second ) does not seem like they tried to skimp on components and its selectable colour. I was looking at circuits and one of the elements is CS98P171 - 8-bit GP-type Microcontroller with OTP ROM crmicro.com/Home/Products/IntelligentC/tyxmcu_en Why would there be a need for MCU in Led Driver ? –